# Как поправить фуллскрин в safari

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть js code

```
$('#full-screen-button-open').on('click', function() {
    goal('fullscreen');
    
    const player = document.querySelector('.presentation-player-slides');
    if (player.requestFullscreen) {
        player.requestFullscreen();            
    } else if (player.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
        player.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (player.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
        player.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
    
    return false;
});
```

Но картинки во время фуллскрина отображается очень криво [image: введите сюда описание изображения]